# Append to each row in a dataframe

Tags: r

It's late and this has to be easy....

Given:

```
a <- c(1,2)
b <- c(3,4)
foo <- data.frame(a,b)
a.leading <- rep(0, 2)
```

How do I append a.leading to each row in foo to look like this?

```
   V1 V2 a b
 1 0  0  1 3
 2 0  0  2 4
```

I know I could just cbind V1 and V2 with only 0's, but how could one do this with either a loop or vectorized function? V1 and V2 do not have to be the names; I can change them later if needed.

Comment: Why would you want to do this with a loop?

Comment: I guess it doesn't have to be a loop; what idea do you have and I will give it a shot. I am having a difficult time explaining what I need. I want to basically lengthen each row of a dataframe by adding zero's to it so I can merge two dataframes together. I am trying to match dimensions of another dataframe to this one.

Comment: `data.frame(t(replicate(nrow(foo),a.leading)),foo)` if you need a specific row vector appended. Otherwise, @TimBiegeleisen 's answer is spot on the money for adding a constant.

Comment: This is what I was needing here. I apologize for not knowing how to word my question properly. Your response was what I am looking for. Also, thank you @TimBiegeleisen for your answer as well. It does work for this example; however this is a scaled down version of the actual problem I have. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method you can use to add columns to a data frame, retaining the same number of rows:

```
new_cols <- c("V1", "V2")   # new columns "V1" and "V2"
foo[new_cols] <- 0          # assigns 0 to each cell in the new columns
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't really loop unless it's either necessary or more efficient.  Here you are adding columns to a matrix-like structure, and `cbind()` is probably the best way to go about it.

You can construct a list for the `...` argument in `cbind.data.frame()`, calling it with `do.call()`.

```
do.call(cbind.data.frame, c(V = as.list(a.leading), foo))
#   V1 V2 a b
# 1  0  0 1 3
# 2  0  0 2 4
```

If you don't like that, you can also do

```
cbind.data.frame(as.list(c(V = a.leading)), foo)
#   V1 V2 a b
# 1  0  0 1 3
# 2  0  0 2 4
```

Comment: Is the .data.frame necessary?

Comment: I figured it might be since they start with one and are adding to it

Comment: `data.frame(c(V = a.leading, foo))` would be simpler overall.

Comment: Right, I over-though it a bit.  I do that ... a lot